# Python Pandas - Save tuple returned from function into 2 seperate columns

Tags: python, pandas

I am using `pandas` to run a function on each row of a dataframe and then save the result into a new column. The problem I am having is my function returns a tuple. The function returns for example...

```
(2345,4837)
```

And I am saving this as a new column by doing...

```
myDataFrame['col5'] = myDataFrame.apply(muFunction, axis=1)
```

This works but I how do I split the return into 2 columns, something like...

```
myDataFrame['col5'] = myDataFrame.apply(muFunction, axis=1)
myDataFrame['col6'] = myDataFrame.apply(muFunction, axis=1)
```

But the first part of the tuple in col5 and the second in col6, anyone have an example?

Comment: can't you split the tuple returned from your function immediately saying `col5, col6 = muFunction`?

Answer (score 2):

Assume that the source DataFrame contains:

```
   A   B   C
0  2   4   6
1  4   8  12
2  5  10  15
3  8  16  24
4  9  18  27
```

The function to apply to it, returning a 2-tuple, is:

```
def myFun(row):
    return row.C + 2, row.C * 2
```

To apply it and save its result in 2 new columns, you can run:

```
df[['X', 'Y']] = df.apply(myFun, axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
```

The result is:

```
   A   B   C   X   Y
0  2   4   6   8  12
1  4   8  12  14  24
2  5  10  15  17  30
3  8  16  24  26  48
4  9  18  27  29  54
```